# Error the "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly C# Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, winforms

It's Windows Forms application.
I got this error when I tried to compile the C# project.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResGenDependencies.GetResXFileInfo(String resxFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.ShouldRebuildResgenOutputFile(String sourceFilePath, String outputFilePath)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.GetResourcesToProcess(List`1& inputsToProcess, List`1& outputsToProcess, List`1& cachedOutputFiles)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Configurator
```

I made the project successfully on VS 2015 Enterprise, I'm getting this error on VS 2013 Community.

I don't know how to solve this. I tried deleting all resource (resx) files from the forms but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First suggestion:**

Completely delete all build outputs and build again, as suggested on [GitHub's MSBuild-issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/364).

**Couple other options:**

Do you happen to have ReSharper? One of its version (I think 8.0) had a bug which caused *The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.* exceptions.

Other option to try is the **DisableOutOfProcTaskHost** property in your [project file](https://cyanbyfuchsia.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/could-not-run-the-generateresource-task-because-msbuild-could-not-create-or-connect-to-a-task-host-with-runtime-clr2-and-architecture-x86/):

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <DisableOutOfProcTaskHost>true</DisableOutOfProcTaskHost>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can also set [DisableOutOfProcTaskHost](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/93727807-f2de-488f-a66c-d9e8d57150f0/solution-stopped-building) as a environment variable.